# What happens when a library is initialized?

Tags: c++, libraries, glfw

I'm using GLFW and am getting confused by the logic of using libraries. According to my understanding of functions, when a function is called, the code within is executed and any memory allocated by said function is deallocated at the end of it. Although when calling `glfwInit()` for example, this allows for the subsequent use of other GLFW functions. My intuition is that this function call would have no effect on the code after it, so how is this happening?

Comment: You can inspect the code what's done in `glfwInit()`. Your intuition is probably wrong.

Comment: global static variables

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes, my intuition is clearly wrong. If you can help me understand the source code it would be greatly appreciated, since I'm not knowledgeable to understand it.

Comment: Your understanding of functions is actually an understanding of local variables. There are more types of variables, like global variables.

Comment: *and any memory allocated by said function is deallocated at the end of it.* That might be true and often is, but nothing in C++ says it must be true.

Comment: @jhed that's way to broad to teach you here.

Comment: Search terms: storage duration, lifetime.